# Problem of data frame and replacement in a loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using R on a dataset containing trips. Each line is a trip (from A to B). On each line, I know the identity of the individual (a number), the purpose of the trip (1,2,3 or 4), the time category (1,2 or 3) and a number identifying the tour in which the trip was done (a tour is a group of trips; all these trips go from A to A).

I would like to create a new row: for the same individual, what was the purpose of the previous trip in the same time category in a different tour. This variable is called "prevDistanceSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour".

I have this error:

> Error in
>   `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`,"prevDistanceSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour", 
>   : replacement has 2 rows, data has 1167

Here is my code:

```
prevPersonTimeCategory <- array(-999, dim=c(3,3))
prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
prevPersonTimeCategory[2,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
prevPersonTimeCategory[3,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
for(i in 2:nrow(TgData)) {
    if (TgData$timeCategory[i] == 1) {
        if (TgData$tour[i] == prevPersonTimeCategory[1,3]) {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                }   
            }
        else {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,3] <- TgData$tour[i]
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2]
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2] <- TgData$purpose[i]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2] <- -999
                }
            }
        }
    else if (TgData$timeCategory[i] == 2) {
        if (TgData$tour[i] == prevPersonTimeCategory[2,3]) {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[2,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[2,2]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[2,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                }   
            }
        else {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[2,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                print(i)
                prevPersonTimeCategory[2,3] <- TgData$tour[i]
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[2,2]
                prevPersonTimeCategory[2,2] <- TgData$purpose[i]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[2,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                prevPersonTimeCategory[2,2] <- -999
                }
            }
        }
    else if (TgData$timeCategory[i] == 3) {
        if (TgData$tour[i] == prevPersonTimeCategory[3,3]) {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[3,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[3,2]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[3,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                }   
            }
        else {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[3,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                prevPersonTimeCategory[3,3] <- TgData$tour[i]
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[3,2]
                prevPersonTimeCategory[3,2] <- TgData$purpose[i]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[3,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                prevPersonTimeCategory[3,2] <- -999
                }
            }
        }
    else {
        TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] = -999
        }
    }
```

I'm creating an array to store information for each time category. In this array, the first value is the identity of the individual (prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1], prevPersonTimeCategory[2,1], prevPersonTimeCategory[3,1], one for each time category), the second is the purpose (prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2], etc.), and the third is the tour number (prevPersonTimeCategory[1,3], etc.).
Then I'm just reading each line (for) and writing a few conditions (if).

I really don't see where I'm doing a mistake.

My dataset contains 36'784 lines, but I'm testing on 1932 lines (-1 line for headers). The data looks like this:

```
PersonID    purpose tour    timeCategory
1   1   1   2
1   4   2   3
1   4   2   3
1   4   3   3
1   3   4   3
1   4   5   3
1   4   5   2
1   4   5   3
1   3   5   3
1   4   6   2
1   4   6   2
1   4   6   3
1   3   7   3
1   4   8   3
1   4   9   3
1   4   10  3
1   4   10  3
1   4   11  1
1   4   12  1
1   4   13  1
1   4   14  1
1   4   16  1
1   1   17  2
1   4   18  3
1   4   19  2
1   3   20  3
1   4   20  3
1   4   21  3
1   1   22  2
1   3   22  3
1   3   23  3
1   4   24  3
1   4   25  3
1   4   25  3
1   4   26  3
1   1   27  2
1   3   27  3
1   4   28  3
1   3   28  3
1   4   29  3
1   4   29  3
1   1   30  2
1   4   31  3
1   1   31  2
1   4   32  3
1   3   32  3
1   4   33  3
1   3   34  3
1   4   35  3
1   1   36  2
1   3   36  3
1   4   37  3
1   3   38  3
1   4   39  3
1   3   39  3
1   4   39  3
1   4   40  3
1   4   40  2
1   4   40  3
1   3   41  3
1   4   42  3
1   4   43  3
1   1   44  2
1   3   45  3
1   4   46  3
1   3   47  3
1   3   47  3
1   4   48  2
1   1   49  2
1   4   50  3
1   1   51  2
1   1   51  2
1   2   51  3
1   3   52  3
1   3   53  1
1   4   54  1
1   4   55  1
1   4   55  1
1   4   55  1
1   1   56  3
1   4   57  3
1   4   58  3
1   1   59  2
1   3   59  3
1   4   60  3
1   4   61  3
1   1   62  3
1   3   63  3
1   4   64  3
1   3   65  3
1   4   66  3
1   3   67  3
1   2   68  1
2   3   69  3
2   1   70  3
2   4   71  2
2   1   72  3
2   3   72  3
2   1   72  2
```

If I run this short version of my code, I have no problems:

```
prevPersonTimeCategory <- array(-999, dim=c(3,3))
prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
prevPersonTimeCategory[2,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
prevPersonTimeCategory[3,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
for(i in 2:nrow(TgData)) {
    if (TgData$timeCategory[i] == 1) {
        if (TgData$tour[i] == prevPersonTimeCategory[1,3]) {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I add a few more lines like here:

```
prevPersonTimeCategory <- array(-999, dim=c(3,3))
prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
prevPersonTimeCategory[2,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
prevPersonTimeCategory[3,1] <- TgData$PersonID[1]
for(i in 2:nrow(TgData)) {
    if (TgData$timeCategory[i] == 1) {
        if (TgData$tour[i] == prevPersonTimeCategory[1,3]) {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                }   
            }
        else {
            if (prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] == TgData$PersonID[i]) {
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,3] <- TgData$tour[i]
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2]
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2] <- TgData$purpose[i]
                }
            else {
                TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour[i] <- -999
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,1] <- TgData$PersonID[i]
                prevPersonTimeCategory[1,2] <- -999
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error comes back:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`,
>   "prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour",  : replacement has 18
>   rows, data has 1150

Comment: tl;dr. Try creating the new column and filling it with NAs before all the looping.

Comment: For your 'my dataset' use dput so people can easily copy and paste it to replicate, run "dput(TgData)". I ran your code and didn't get an error. If I had to have a guess where you could be going wrong I think you maybe need some 'i' indices on the left hand side of your 'assign', because at the moment you're always putting your results into the same cells, or is that the intention? Try running each 'if' chunk at a time to see which one specifically is giving you the error.

Comment: terrible question. Try to narrow the code down to a minimal version which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new empty column as joran suggested works.

run this before you start the loop

TgData$prevPurposeSameTimeCategoryDifferentTour <- NA

Comment: how do i get around if i get same error in for loop even after i add new columns with NA's before for loop?